# The "cmsBaseUrl" is not set according to the information in civicrm.settings.php

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, civicrm.settings.php, cv

**Error:**

When I check the installation requirements (`cv core:check-req`) I get an error message that says:

> The "cmsBaseUrl" (http://localhost/usr/local/bin/usr/local/bin/) is
> unavailable or malformed. Consider setting it explicitly.

Despite this message, there have never been any errors related to the base url when operating the site. I only noticed it when I ran the above check.

**Setup:**

I installed CiviCRM on Drupal8 with the following cv command:

```
cv core:install --cms-base-url="https://example.org" --lang="de_DE" -m loadGenerated=1 -v
```

And looking in `civicrm.settings.php` I can see that the base url is set with:

```
if (!defined('CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL'      , 'https://example.org');
}
```

**Troubleshooting attempts:**

In `civicrm.settings.php` it says:

> IMPORTANT: Trailing slashes should be used on all URL settings.

Accordingly, I changed `https://example.org` to `https://example.org/` in that file.

I then cleaned up the Drupal and CiviCRM cashes via the admin interface. The error message remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run check-req with the `--cms-base-url` argument? It needs to be specified there too.

Comment: which tool uses check-req? Thanks, Josh

Comment: I figured it it out. It is cv core:check-req

Comment: I ran `cv core:check-req --cms-base-url="https://example.com"` and it worked. No more error message. However, it doesn't seem to matter what I specify in the argument as long as it is a valid URL syntax. Thank you. :)